Install of MariaDB hangs. What to do to ensure it proceeds to completion?
My environment:  UbuntuMATE 20.04 on Amd64 box
Linux hostname 5.4.0-176-generic #196-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 22 16:46:39 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Log of attempted install session:
root@OasisMega1:~# apt install mariadb-server -y

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bogofilter bogofilter-bdb bogofilter-common cli-common espeak-ng-data gir1.2-gtkspell3-3.0 libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0
  libdotconf0 libenca0 libespeak-ng1 libgdiplus libgfortran-10-dev libglib2.0-cil libgnome-autoar-gtk-0-0 libgtk2.0-cil libjbig-dev
  libjxr-tools libllvm11 libllvm9 liblzma-dev libmecab2 libmessaging-menu0 libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.5-cil
  libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil
  libmono-system-core4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libnetcdff7 libpcaudio0 libphonenumber7 libpst4 libsonic0 libspeechd2 libtiffxx5
  libvpx-dev libxpm-dev libytnef0 linux-headers-5.4.0-173 linux-headers-5.4.0-173-generic linux-image-5.4.0-173-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-173-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-173-generic mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mono-runtime-common
  mono-runtime-sgen optipng python3-apsw python3-attr python3-brlapi python3-defusedxml python3-feedparser python3-html2text
  python3-html5-parser python3-ifaddr python3-jinja2 python3-louis python3-mechanize python3-msgpack python3-odf python3-pyatspi
  python3-pypeg2 python3-pyqt5.qtopengl python3-pyqt5.qtquick python3-pyqt5.qtsql python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel
  python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine python3-repoze.lru python3-routes python3-ruamel.yaml python3-sane python3-speechd python3-zeroconf
  sound-icons ubuntu-touch-sounds
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-server-core-10.3
Suggested packages:
  mariadb-test tinyca
Recommended packages:
  libhtml-template-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-server-core-10.3
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 107 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 mariadb-server-core-10.3 amd64 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [6,250 kB]
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 mariadb-server-10.3 amd64 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [4,202 kB]
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 mariadb-server all 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [12.7 kB]
Fetched 10.5 MB in 1s (8,330 kB/s)         
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server-core-10.3.
(Reading database ... 545075 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server-core-10.3_1%3a10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server-core-10.3 (1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server-10.3.
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server-10.3_1%3a10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server-10.3 (1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server_1%3a10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server (1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-core-10.3 (1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-10.3 (1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service → /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service → /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.

    { at this point a progress bar is displayed and the process hangs at about 69% }

    { after waiting 15 minutes with no visible progress, I terminate the install by 
      entering the command   '/bin/systemctl stop mariadb.service' }

Job for mariadb.service canceled.
Setting up mariadb-server (1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...

root@OasisMega1:~# 

I did a full apt purge before each of two re-attempts, and it still hung up each time at the same spot.
Any ideas on how to overcome the roadblock?

See if the database process has logged any errors to journal or another log file in /var/log.
